# I have an issue about short cut setting

Tags: shortcut

I assigned the quick favorites' key as "Alt + Q"
it's working in object mode, but somewhat it's not working in edit mode...
Does anyone know how to handle this problem?
I would be really glad, if someone can answer to this question thanks.

Comment: there might be some conflict, you can open preference-keymap and input alt q to search which shortcut use this key.then change it if you don't need it.

Comment: @NatureK You beat me to it while I was grabbing a screenshot. You are correct.

Comment: thank you all!! those really helped me! a looot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to remove or re-assign conflicting keymaps.
[image]

Comment: thank you soooo much!!! I thought I did search this. which I didn't..

Comment: @Seong if the answer is correct, mark it as such (on the top left of the answer)

Comment: @moonboots thanks for letting me know!